# Defining value of PI

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, pi

I am working on a new project and I am trying to write the cleanest, easiest to read and hopefully, most efficient, code I can.

I need to use PI but apparently it isn't defined in math.h. So I read about doing this:

```
const double PI = atan(1.0)*4
```

But I get this error:

> A function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

Any ideas on why? How can I get PI as a constant?

Also, please, I am trying to learn as much as I can with this project, so it would be great if you could also explain why your answer would work. Thanks!

Comment: -1 [Looks like it works just fine to me](http://ideone.com/zoNRM). You need to show _real_ code -- [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: There's `M_PI` in the `cmath` header.

Comment: Possibly related? [M_PI works with math.h but not with cmath in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563810/m-pi-works-with-math-h-but-not-with-cmath-in-visual-studio)

Comment: If your compiler supports `constexpr`, check [this](https://gist.github.com/1491172).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>

const double PI = M_PI;
```

You can't call a function for a global `const double` because the constant needs to be evaluated at compile time.  At runtime `atan()` could be anything.  You could arrange for it to be called once at startup, but using an actual PI constant that's already available is better.

(actually using `M_PI` directly would also be good)

EDIT:  It took many comment upvotes and re-reading my own answer over a year later to see why people were up in arms about my statement about constants.  I was jumping over a step: As everyone is saying you can initialize `const double` at runtime just as easily as `double`.  *However,* if you are using a global variable (instead of a constant expression) to store pi you will defeat some optimization opportunities.  Some experiments with `gcc` suggest this isn't even as bad as I thought, which suggests a whole new question...

Comment: *"I need to use PI but apparently it isn't defined in math.h."* he says in the question.

Comment: @CodyGray: It's not, it's `M_PI`

Comment: Since when does a constant need to be evaluated at compile time?  Some contexts would need a *constant integral expression*, but this isn't integral either...

Comment: Just a side-note - for `M_PI` to work on MSVC you'll need to define `_USE_MATH_DEFINES`.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
const double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209;
```

This seems to me to be cleaner, easier to read, and more efficient than `atan(1.0)*4`.

Comment: +1 and worth to say that double has about 17 significant decimal places, the floating point literal therefore can be much shorter.

Comment: @Christian : That's true on most common platforms, but ultimately it's implementation-defined; there are platforms with 128-bit doubles (yielding ~34 decimal numbers) that could take advantage of this declaration, and meanwhile it doesn't negatively affect the platforms that don't.

Answer (score 5):

You have mis-tagged the question.  In C++ the following is well-defined and will compile:

```
#include <math.h>

const double PI = atan(1.0)*4;
```

But in C, initializers at file scope are not allowed to.

In C you'll either need to use a non-standard macro (such as `M_PI` in GCC), create your own appropriate macro or literal ([Ned Batchelder has done the hard part for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040584/12711)), or initialize it in your own function at an appropriately early enough time.

Comment: I'm being downvoted over a semantic detail about constant expressions for file scope variables and this post has 3 votes and defines `PI` to be 6.23.

Comment: @Ben: Yup - a bit embarrassing on the typo here (fixed it).  FWIW, I upvoted your answer - I assumed the downvotes on it were because `M_PI` doesn't 'just work' on MSVC.

Comment: @Ben : Stating that constants must be evaluated at compile-time in C++ is not a semantic detail, it's merely wrong.

Comment: @ildjarn: Since my answer got accepted I encourage anyone to edit it to be correct/precise.

Answer (score 0):

How about **assembly language** ?

```
fldpi
```

It is just alternative using Floating-Point Instruction