# constexpr replacements for math constants like M_PI

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr, cmath

Are there any C++11 `constexpr` constants which can be used instead of the constant macros from `<cmath>`, i.e. constants like `M_PI` and friends? Or lacking that, any global `const` values which provide these constants at runtime?

Comment: What benefit would `constexpr` make? The macros are constant expressions, no?

Comment: @Pubby: `constexpr` vs. macro: main benefit would be clean namespace handling, and the fact that issues like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6563810/1468366) were perhaps less likely. `constexpr` vs. simple `const`: one could be sure to use them at compile time, e.g. to compute template arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no predefined constexpr or global const constants defined in C++ standard library. But you can define them by yourself like, for example:

```
namespace MathConstants {
    const double E =            2.71828182845904523536;
    const double LOG2E =        1.44269504088896340736;
    const double LOG10E =       0.434294481903251827651;
    const double LN2 =          0.693147180559945309417;
    const double LN10 =         2.30258509299404568402;
    const double PI =           3.14159265358979323846;
    const double PI_2 =         1.57079632679489661923;
    const double PI_4 =         0.785398163397448309616;
    const double PI_1_PI =      0.318309886183790671538;
    const double PI_2_PI =      0.636619772367581343076;
    const double PI_2_SQRTPI =  1.12837916709551257390;
    const double SQRT2 =        1.41421356237309504880;
    const double SQRT1_2 =      0.707106781186547524401;
};
```

Or use boost math constant templates, some documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/constants.html) (haven't used it).

Comment: +1 for the boost pointer. Seems like in recent versions the stuff has been moved out of the internals subpackage, so its API should be reasonably stable. See [recent documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/constants.html).