# M_PI issue in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm having problems compiling a c++ project that include cmath with Visual Studio 2012 and I get this error

> `error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identifier`

I've tried this [M_PI works with math.h but not with cmath in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563810/m-pi-works-with-math-h-but-not-with-cmath-in-visual-studio) but it doesn't work at all

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT**

the application source code I downloaded a couple of weeks ago was not stable. So today I tried to download the updated sources and now it works like a charm

Comment: So you put `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` and `#include <cmath>` as high as possible in your include chain, but that did not change anything?

Comment: If you do a simple search you would have found out that `M_PI` is not part of the C++ (or the C) standard. They are part of the [POSIX standard though](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html). Other systems may have it as an extension.

Comment: Yes Frédéric I did exactly that

Comment: Can you show a [minimal code sample demonstrating the issue](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I think it's a bit hard because I'm trying to compile the [Stellarium source code](http://www.stellarium.org/) But I'm pretty sure that it is not an issue related to their code because they explain all in [this guide](http://stellarium.org/wiki/index.php/Compile_with_MSVC2012_and_Qt5_(OpenGL))

Comment: I'm trying to ask them why this appends. I'll tell you if I'm able to solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried adding it to Visual Studio's project `Preprocessor Definitions`?

Answer (score 1):

put the following code in a header file and include it, where You need M_PI

```
#pragma once
#include <cmath>
#ifndef M_PI
namespace
{
    const double M_PI = std::acos(-1.0);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Or just define M_PI inside your own Math.h, and only directly include your own header.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the header of your program:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
```

And use `M_PI` to access the number.