# M_PI flagged as undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, development-environment, compile-time-constant

When I compile the code below, I got these error messages:

```
(Error  1   error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identifier 
2   IntelliSense: identifier "M_PI" is undefined)
```

What is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double my_sqrt1( double n );`enter code here`

int main() {
double k[5] = {-100, -10, -1, 10, 100};
int i;

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    double val = M_PI * pow( 10.0, k[i] );
    cout << "n: "
         << val
         << "\tmysqrt: "
         << my_sqrt1(val)
         << "\tsqrt: "
         << sqrt(val)
         << endl;
}

return 0;
}

double my_sqrt1( double n ) {
int i;
double x = 1;


for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    x = ( x + n / x ) / 2;
}

return x;
}
```

Comment: M_PI is not actually part of the standard, so no guarantee that it's been defined in math.h

Comment: Does this answer your question? [M\_PI works with math.h but not with cmath in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563810/m-pi-works-with-math-h-but-not-with-cmath-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 110):

It sounds like you're using MS stuff, according to [their docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6.aspx)

> Math Constants are not defined in Standard C/C++. To use them, you must first define _USE_MATH_DEFINES and then include cmath or math.h.

So you need something like

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```

as a header.

Comment: i am using Visual Studio 2013 this is why that is not running right? is it running in g++ ?

Comment: Dear Eunsu,if you go inside the head file <math.h> inside "Exsternal Dependencies" of Visual Studio 2013, you can see that this is part of the code:

'#if defined (_USE_MATH_DEFINES) && !defined (_MATH_DEFINES_DEFINED)
/*   ****   */
#define M_PI       3.14159265358979323846
/*   ****   */
#endif'

If you want to use this #define M_PI you MUST define _USE_MATH_DEFINES with an #define. This is the reason!

Comment: It makes sense but doesn't work for me... I am using VS 2015 Community...

Comment: Same with VS2019, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 40):

`math.h` does not define `M_PI` by default.

So go with this:

```
#ifndef M_PI
    #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif
```

This will handle both cases either your header have `M_PI` defined or not.

Answer (score 15):

`M_PI` is supported by GCC too, but you've to do some work to get it

```
#undef __STRICT_ANSI__
#include <cmath>
```

or if you don't like to pollute your source file, then do

```
g++ -U__STRICT_ANSI__ <other options>
```

Comment: C++ headers have macros, includes, variables, functions and classes -- declared, defined or both.  Now depending on a few flags (lookup _conditional compilation_) the pre-processor includes / excludes them.  Strictly speaking, the C++ standard doesn't mandate `M_PI` and hence GCC's header defaults to not including its definition. If someone needs it, they've to ask for it by undefining the guard that excludes it i.e. `__STRICT_ANSI__`. You can search your compiler's `math.h` (original C header of `cmath`) for `M_PI` and you'd see the guards surrounding it. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Worked for me under Win10 + Msys2 Portable.

Answer (score 15):

As noted by shep above you need something like

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```

However you also include `iostream`.

`iostream` includes a lot of stuff and one of those things eventually includes `cmath`. This means that by the time you include it in your file all the symbols have already been defined so it is effectively ignored when you include it and the `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` doesn't work

If you include `cmath` before `iostream` it should give you the higher precision constants like `M_PI`

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Good advice!  I'd alter it slightly to advise putting definitions like that before *all* `#include` directives and not just single out `iostream`.  In any case, your explanation is spot-on.  I'd give it two up-votes, if allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Use this include for Windows 10 (and Windows 11):

```
#include <corecrt_math_defines.h>
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if cross-compiling on MSYS. It seems in that case, you'll want to avoid including this file and instead #define USE_MATH_DEFINES.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` **before** other headers like this:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#incude other headers...
```

Answer (score 1):

I used C99 in NetBeans with remote linux host with its build tools.
Try adding `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and add the `-lm` during linking.