# Why is M_PI undefined in one file, but defined in main.cpp?

Tags: c++, header-files, cmath

I have a Code::Blocks project with a few files, including `main.cpp`, `Line_segment.cpp`and its corresponding header, `Line_segment.h`. The header file, as well as the main file, `#include` the `<cmath>` library in their preprocessor directives. One of the objects defined in `<cmath>` is the constant `M_PI`, which is simply the number pi.

Using `M_PI` works just fine in `main()`, and I'm able to write simple things like `std::cout << M_PI*2. << '\n'` and I'll get an output of 6.28... as expected. However, when I try to do the same thing in the `Line_segment.cpp` file and compile, I get a compilation error saying that `'M_PI' was not declared in this scope`. The same happens if I include `<cmath>` directly into the .cpp file, and if I try using `"math.h"`. Another observation is that `M_PI`, `M_PI_2` and `M_PI_4` all show up in the code suggestion popup when I type the name out, which implies that Code::Blocks is recognizing the name in the scope of that file.

Is there any known reason why this happens? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A [mcve] goes a long way.

Comment: ... ^ and never had gone to be happening actually otherwise-

Comment: `M_PI` is *de facto* standard, but it's not standard in the sense of being defined by the ISO C++ standard (the *de jure* standard). And so its definition is probably protected by some preprocessor symbol. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065359/m-pi-flagged-as-undeclared-identifier for info relevant to g++ and MSVC.

Comment: My own theory is that in 2035, when use of C++ has declined to almost nothing, the standardization committee will hit on the idea of standardizing *existing practice*, instead of inventing new stuff, and then `M_PI` may stand a chance of being standardized. However, they'll probably change the name to something less obvious.

Comment: After some experimentation, I found that the M_PI is defined when I `#include "SDL.h"`, the graphics library. SDL was included in my `main` file but not tin the `line_segment` file. Any ideas why this happens?