# invalid type argument of unary '*' (have double)

Tags: c++

Just started learning c++ got this error:

`C:\Users\KC\Documents\Math.cpp|9|error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'double')|`

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define M_PI
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double area, radius = 1.5;
      area = M_PI * radius * radius;
   cout << area << "\n";
}
```

can someone explain to me what did I do wrong. Thanks

Comment: You haven’t put a value for M_PI.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563810/m-pi-works-with-math-h-but-not-with-cmath-in-visual-studio  .   Without a value for M_PI, your area assignment simply becomes ‘area = * radius * radius’.   Hence the error.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Some standard libraries define their own `M_PI` when <cmath> is included. I'd highly recommend picking a different name or else you're asking for a collision and undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chris how is a colliding `M_PI` preprocessor symbol supposed to cause undefined behviour?

Comment: @P.W I'm using Code :: Blocks

Comment: @JonathanGoh: Code::Blocks is an IDE. Asked for compiler because, the answer will depend on that as you can already see.

Comment: @P.W Sorry, just recalled it's the GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: @user463035818, I misremembered. Yes, you'll get a compiler error, which isn't ideal over having the program be portable, but better than UB. (I believe I was mixing it up with multiple [ODR-related](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12) definitions.)

Answer (score 4):

```
#define M_PI
```

should be

```
#define M_PI 3.14159
```

(or whatever value you want to give for pi).

You defined `M_PI` as nothing, which means that this code

```
  area = M_PI * radius * radius;
```

becomes this code

```
  area = * radius * radius;
```

and your compiler is complaining about the unexpected `*`.

Comment: This is one reason why `constexpr double M_PI` would be better imo. You can't forget to assign a value

Comment: yeah That was the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```

and remove this line:

```
#define M_PI
```

More info in this answer: [M_PI works with math.h but not with cmath in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563810/m-pi-works-with-math-h-but-not-with-cmath-in-visual-studio)

Comment: +1 best answer as no one should redefine pi. though it is quite upsetting that it doesn't work in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You used the preprocessor directive `#define M_PI` which defined `M_PI` as an empty string. So, after substitution of the empty contents for `M_PI`, the expression

```
area = M_PI * radius * radius
```

became

```
area = * radius * radius
```

and the first asterisk became an unary operator, with the whole expression interpreted as

```
area = (* radius) * radius
```

That unary asterisk can't reasonably work with a `double` argument, hence an error message.