# nvcc compilation errors with "M_PI" and "or"

Tags: cuda, nvcc, cl

When trying to compile this piece of code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

void minimal_example(){
    int i=2;
    if(i==3 or i==4) printf("I want %d!\n",M_PI);
}
```

using

```
nvcc -x cu -Xcompiler=/permissive- -dc cuda_nvcc_cl_test.cu -o cuda_nvcc_cl_test.obj
```

I get the follwing errors (in line 7):

```
error: expected a ")"
error: identifier "M_PI" is undefined
```

I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio's cl.exe (Version 19.16.27031.1 for x64) and CUDA toolkit 10.1.

When replacing `cmath` with `math.h` and `or` with `||` (alternatively add `#include <ciso646>`), the errors disappear. However, are there some compiler options or other possibilities so that I can keep the code as is?

Also why did `-Xcompiler=/permissive-` not help?

Comment: `M_PI` is also defined in `cmath` via include of `math.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. Apparently `nvcc` includes `cmath` prior to parsing your code.  As discussed in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563810/m-pi-works-with-math-h-but-not-with-cmath-in-visual-studio), if you include `cmath` and you don't have the define instantiated at that point, you won't get `M_PI` defined, *and* subsequent inclusions of `cmath` won't fix this, due to include guards.  A possible workaround for this is to add `-D_USE_MATH_DEFINES` to your compile command line.  This puts the define in place from the start of the compilation process, and `M_PI` gets defined that way.
2. Contrary to what I read as correct or standard behavior, the use of `or` in place of `||` seems to be conditioned on inclusion of `ciso646` (on `nvcc` on windows/visual studio only.  `nvcc` on linux doesn't seem to need this).  Yes, I understand it is not supposed to work that way, but nevertheless it appears to be necessary.  [This may be an issue with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/555524/1695960).  You can experiment with the `/Za` switch if you like.   (It didn't seem to help when I tried it.)

With CUDA 10.1, on VS2019, when I compile this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ciso646>

void minimal_example(){
    int i=2;
    if(i==3 or i==4) printf("I want %f!\n",M_PI);
}
```

with this command line:

```
nvcc -x cu -dc test.cu -o test.obj -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

I get no errors or warnings.  Note that I have also changed your `printf` format specifier from `%d` to `%f` to be consistent with the type of `M_PI`.

If you really don't want to include `ciso646`, `nvcc` [supports](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications) the `-include` switch to include a file directly from the command line.  Therefore I can compile this:

```
#include <cstdio>

void minimal_example(){
    int i=2;
    if(i==3 or i==4) printf("I want %f!\n",M_PI);
}
```

like this:

```
nvcc -x cu -dc test.cu -o test.obj -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -include ciso646
```

with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative! Do you have insight on why -Xcompiler=/permissive- did not work? I was hoping it will pass the permissive- option to the cl compiler. PS: Sry for the d/f typo in printf.

Comment: I don't know what you were expecting with that switch and "did not work"  or "not help" doesn't shed any light on it for me.  Have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019) for it?  What were you expecting that switch to do in this case?  What did not work?   Note that `permissive-` with the minus sign at the end makes the compiler **more restrictive**.  It disables languange permissive behavior and attempts to perform more strict compliance.

Comment: Also note from the docs linked above that `permissive-` appears to be the default behavior starting with later versions of VS2017.  So I'm not sure that adding it would make any difference; it is already on by default.

Comment: To be more clear, my expectation was that with `/permissive-` I would not get errors regarding the use of `or` based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414124/why-does-vs-not-define-the-alternative-tokens-for-logical-operators